# Sort xtable() output by p-value from glm model summary

Tags: r, xtable

I'm modelling a lot of data for different companies, and for each company I need to identify quickly those model parameters that are most significant. What I would like to see is `xtable()` output for a fitted model that sorts all coefficients in increasing order of p-value (ie, most significant parameters first).

```
x <- data.frame(a=rnorm(100), b=runif(100), c=rnorm(100), e=rnorm(100))
fit <- glm(a ~ ., data=x)
xtable(fit)
```

I'm *guessing* that I may be able to accomplish something like this by messing with the structure of the `fit` object. But I'm not familiar with the structure enough to be able to confidently change anything.

Suggestions?

Comment: `str()` is your friend when you want to inspect an R object. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not necessarily the most elegant solution, but that should do the job:

```
data(birthwt, package="MASS")
glm.res <- glm(low ~ ., data=birthwt[,-10])
idx <- order(coef(summary(glm.res))[,4])  # sort out the p-values
out <- coef(summary(glm.res))[idx,]       # reorder coef, SE, etc. by increasing p
library(xtable)
xtable(out)
```

[image]

Comment: Seems reasonably direct. Uses extractor functions properly. What's not to like?

Comment: Does exactly what I want it to. Thanks chl.